# Three20: A lot of semantic issues

Tags: ios, three20

I've imported Three20 into my new project with the Terminal. When I build the project, I've get 13 errors, semantic issues. How to fix this or any other ideas?

Screenshot: [image]

Thanks!

Comment: 1). Don't use three20 2). That is all

Answer (score 2):

This framework is no longer maintained. However, if you want to get a version that doesn't have any xcode 4.5 issues, download the development branch of the project https://github.com/facebook/three20/tree/development.

That should include the fixes you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

From what I've heard, that library is a mess.

As for the errors:

Which complier are you using? New compiler (*Apple LLVM 4.1*, if I am correct), automatically creates those "underscore ivars" without you needing to synthesize them:

e.g. (before new compiler):

`@property (nonatomic) NSObjectTypeOrWhatever *tapCount`

`@synthesize tapCount=_tapCount`

With new compiler, you only need to declare property and "underscore ivars" are generated for you.

So I suppose you have two options,

1. change your compiler to match a new one (LLVM 4.1)
2. Manually synthesize those properties

(first one is faster)

Comment: try then sythesize those properties or try @Kris Gellci's solution which uses getter/setter(s).

Answer (score 0):

Just throw self. In front of everything, for example, the first line should be self.tapCount instead of _tapCount.